# Can I set es.batch.write.retry.count to zero value

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I just want to stop spark job if any Exception occur while writing data to ES.
There is one configuration es.batch.write.retry.count whose default value is 3.
Is it make valid that we can set es.batch.write.retry.count = 0 so that if something breaks as per my requirement spark data frame writing will stop there to ES ?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of es.batch.write.retry.count just handle of how much time to try write to elastic for each batch before giving up and move to the next batch, it doesnt influence on your spark job.
The workaround u can do is to set spark.task.maxFailures=1, but it will influence ur entire job and not only the write to elasticsearch.

You sohuld notice that because the writing to elastic isn`t transactional, if one task of writing to elastic failed, it doesnt mean the some of your data already have been written to elastic.

I dont know what is your usecase over here, but if you want make sure that all of your data is written into elasticsearch, you should make a _count query and check if it equal to df.count() after the writing(assumed that you are writing to new index).

Comment: Similar situation for me, i was ingesting data into elastic search via spark executors, when there are parallel executors upto 10, i started to see the 429, tried es.retry.wait and es.retry.count which is  of no use, code says it's using exponential backoff algorithm, with spark speed elastic search is not coping up, don't know what to do now

Comment: One good thing is i was able to send 128mb of 400 records(very huge record), elastic search 6.8.0 or spark should give support exponential retrying logic